# SwiftUI pass data to subview

Tags: swift, swiftui

So I have read a lot about swiftUI and I am confused. I understand the `@State` and how it update the view behind the scenes. The thing I can't understand is why when I the subview in this example is automatically updated when the state changes in the top view/struct given the fact that on the subview the var `subname` is not a `@State` property. I would expect this not to be updated. Can someone enlighten me please?

```
import SwiftUI

struct SwiftUIView: View {
    @State private var name = "George"
    var body: some View {
        VStack{
            SubView(subName: name).foregroundColor(.red)
            Button(action: {
                self.name = "George2"
            }) {
                Text("Change view name")
            }
        }
    }
}

struct SubView: View {
    var subName:String
    var body: some View {
        Text(subName)
    }
}

struct SwiftUIView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        SwiftUIView()
    }
}
```

PS.
If I change the subview to

```
struct SubView: View {
    @State var subName:String
    var body: some View {
        Text(subName)
    }
}
```

it's not updated when I press the button.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

#### var subName: String

```
struct SubView: View {
    var subName: String
    // ...
}
```

In the above example you don't really have a state. When the `subName` property in the parent view changes, the whole `SubView` is redrawn and thus provided with a new value for the `subName` property. It's basically a constant (try changing it to `let`, you'll have the same result).

#### @State var subName: String

```
struct SubView: View {
    @State var subName: String
    // ...
}
```

Here you do have a `@State` property which is initialised once (the first time the `SubView` is created) and remains the same even when a view is redrawn. Whenever you change the `subName` variable in the parent view, in the SubView it will stay the same (it may be modified from within the SubView but will not change the parent's variable).

#### @Binding var subName: String

```
struct SubView: View {
    @Binding var subName: String
    // ...
}
```

If you have a `@Binding` property you can directly access the parent's `@State` variable. Whenever it's changed in the parent it's changed in the SubView (and the other way around) - that's why it's called *binding*.

Answer (score 4):

Whenever an `@State` property of a `View` changes, the view is refreshed, which means its whole `body` is recalculate. Since `SubView` is part of the `body` of `SwiftUIView`, whenever `SwiftUIView` refreshes itself, it redraws its `SubView` using the new value of its `@State name` property.